# Proving of Inequalities

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, real-numbers

How to prove:

If $a>0$ and $b>0$, and $a^2>b^2$, then $a>b.$

I've tried different methods but I really can't prove this one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add the different methods you've tried. It helps to see what work you've done first, and it makes your question more useful.

Answer (score 1):

$a^2>b^2$ is equivalent to $(a-b)(a+b)>0$. Since $a+b>0$ for your hypothesis, you have (rule of signs) $a-b>0$.

That is, $a>b$.